# Attach a branch to another, performing the same commands on both

Tags: git

Something I often find myself doing is this:

```
[dev and master branches are on the same commit]
git checkout master
[do some minor fixes]
git add . & git commit-m"minor fix"
git push
git checkout dev
git rebase master
git push
git checkout master
```

Is there a way of avoiding the `git checkout dev` part? I am imagining something along the lines of `git checkout master & git attach master dev`, which would cause all commands performed on master to be performed on the dev branch as well (assuming they start at the same point).

Comment: `git branch -f dev master`? If you do that so often, what's the point of the `dev` branch?

Comment: @Mat I am not sure when and how to implement your suggestion. I try to make it a habit to not make major changes in the master branch, but sometimes when I push to master in order to deploy I only notice small errors e.g. typos after the fact, which I then promptly fix. This is the time that I would like to avoid switching to dev and still have them be up to date.

Comment: `git checkout dev` and `git rebase master` can be combined in to a single `git rebase master dev`, at least.

Answer (score 0):

`git branch -f dev master` as suggested by a comment will work only if you want `dev` to be at *exactly* the same commit as master. Then just run it right after `git commit`.

If there's something more on `dev` you want preserved, and you really want a rebase, use either [a regular bash alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62088734/git-short-command-for-checking-out-pulling-prune-fetching-and-deleting) or a git alias:

`$> git config alias.devattach '!git checkout dev && git rebase master && git push && git checkout master'`

Doing `git devattach` will perform all these for you, stopping whenever one of the command in the pipe fails.

**EDIT** Missed you wanted this parametrized, so:

`$> git config alias.attach '!git checkout $2 && git rebase $1 && git push && git checkout $1'`

Now `git attach master dev` does what you wanted.