# Git short command for checking out, pulling, prune fetching and deleting

Tags: bash, git, github

Is there a shortcut for:

1. Checking out on master
2. Pulling from master
3. Prune Fetch *(check which remote branches are removed)*
4. Delete those local branches

**Scenario:**
Let's say I'm on master and I checkout on the branch `foo`, I do some commits and publish `foo` to remote and push to it as well. Next I merge that branch to `master` on GitHub and delete the online version of `foo` since it's complete. Now in the offline environment, I have to do the following:

```sh
$ git checkout master
$ git pull
$ git fetch -p
$ git branch -d foo
```

or shorthand:

```
git checkout master && git pull && git fetch -p && git branch -D foo
```

Is there a command I can execute to make this much shorter? Like

```sh
$ git complete foo
```

or something along those lines..?

Comment: how about using bash aliases?

Comment: @Ashok Arora Yep, I just found out about them haha, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aliases` can be used for solving this problem.

An alias can be created by running:

```
$ alias cpfb="git checkout master && git pull && git fetch -p && git branch -D"
```

Now, you can execute

```
$ cpfb foo
```

which will execute those commands specified in the alias.

Setting alias through terminal lasts for only that particular terminal instance.

Hence, save them in ~/.bashrc to make the alias permanent.

Comment: Just curious: why not a Git alias?

Comment: @customcommander Just a personal preference, I like to keep aliases under the shell since I usually backup bashrc. Also, there's no simple way to view all the git aliases like with bash. It requires creating another alias xD.

Comment: `git config --get-regexp alias` will show all your Git aliases

Comment: @AshokArora The big disadvantage of shell aliases is that one has to reload them into the current shell (all shells in all terminals, actually) if one was changed. Git aliases are auto-reloaded because git stops after every single command. The 2nd big disadvantage is shell aliases are hard to use in scripts — one has to explicitly include them in every shell script; global git aliases are always available. My preference is: 1st, git aliases; 2nd shell scripts; 3rd shell aliases. IMO shell aliases are good only when you can't do without them because they change the current shell's environment.